# Is there a way to discern an object from the background with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I always wanted to have a device that, from a live camera feed, could detect an object, create a 3D model of it, and then identify it.  It would work a lot like the Scanner tool from Subnautica.  Imagine my surprise when I found OpenCV, a free-to-use computer vision tool for Python!

My first step is to get the computer to recognize that there is an object at the center of the camera feed.  To do this, I found a [Canny() function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-canny-function/?ref=rp) that could detect edges and display them as white lines in a black image, which should make a complete outline of the object in the center.  I also used the floodFill() function to fill in the black zone between the white lines with gray, which would show that the computer recognizes that there is an object there.  My attempt is in the following image.

[The red dot is the center of the live video.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQPu7.png)

The issue is that the edge lines can have holes in them due to a blur between two colors, which can range from individual pixels to entire missing lines.  As a result, the gray gets out and doesn't highlight me as the only object, and instead highlights the entire wall as well.  Is there a way to fill those missing pixels in or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: just take a course/class on computer vision.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO and the exiting world of machine vision !

What you are describing is a *very* classical problem in the field, and not a trivial one at all. It depends heavily on the shape and appearance of what you define as the object of interest and the overall structure, homogeneity and color of the background. Remember, the computer has no concept of what an "object" is, the only thing it 'knows' is a matrix of numbers.

In your example, you might start out with selecting the background area by color (or hue, look up HSV). Everything else is your object. This is what classical greenscreening techniques do, and it only works with (a) a homogenous background, which does not share a color with your object and (b) a single or multiple not overlapping objects.

The problem with your edge based approach is that you won't get a closed edge safely, and deciding where the inside and outside of the object is might get tricky.

Advanced ways to do this would get you into Neural Network territory, but maybe try to get the basics down first.

Here are two links to tutorials on converting color spaces and extracting contours:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

If you got that figured out, look into stereo vision or 3D imaging in general, and that subnautica scanner might just become reality some day ;)

Good luck !